# access the value of two inputs outside of the event

Tags: javascript, input, event-handling

I want to access value of the two inputs to make calculation immediately when their values are set

```
<script>
//I want to access value of the two inputs to make calculation immediately when their values are set
const heightInputEl = document.querySelector('.height-input');
const weightInputEl = document.querySelector('.weight-input');
  heightInputEl.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  const height = Number(e.target.value);
  const mtrsqr = Math.abs(Math.pow(height / 100, 2));
});

weightInputEl.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  const weight = Number(e.target.value);
});

</script>
```

Comment: call a function inside the event handler that does what you require

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mtrsqr
var weight

const heightInputEl = document.querySelector('.height-input');
const weightInputEl = document.querySelector('.weight-input');

heightInputEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let height = Number(heightInputEl.value);
  mtrsqr = Math.abs(Math.pow(height / 100, 2));
});

weightInputEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
  weight = Number(weightInputEl.value);
});
```

By defining mtrsqr and weight outisde the event, we can access them anywhere

Comment: I'm getting undefined as the result of it, trying to access them

Comment: Could you update your original post, with the code you are running? Or is it just mine? If yes, then what line is giving undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably not running because it ran even before the said html elements are loaded. Try setTimeout and it should work perfectly as demonstrated in this example using your code - https://jsfiddle.net/hiyer/sL18nqe7/36/

```
<html>

<script>
  //i want to access value of the two input to make calculation immediately they put in a value
 setTimeout( function (){
        const heightInputEl = document.querySelector('.height-input');
    const weightInputEl = document.querySelector('.weight-input');
    heightInputEl.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    const height = Number(e.target.value);
    const mtrsqr = Math.abs(Math.pow(height / 100, 2));
    const mtrsqrEl = document.querySelector('#mtrsqr');
    mtrsqrEl.textContent=""+mtrsqr;
    
      });

   weightInputEl.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    const weight = Number(e.target.value);
    const weightEL = document.querySelector('#weight');
        weightEL.textContent=weight;   
  });

},100);

</script>
<body>
      Height:<input class="height-input" value="10"/ >
      <br/>
      Weight:<input class="weight-input" value="10">
      <br/>
      Mtrsqr:<label id="mtrsqr"></label>
      <br/>
      Weight:<label id="weight"></label>
      <br/>
</body>


</html>
```